# side menu, not show top to bottom of page, only between header/footer

Tags: html, css

Being somewhat new to all this, I am not sure if it is even possible to do what I am thinking, but here goes --  Right now, my side menu goes from the top of the page to the bottom.  What I would like to happen is that it only appear between the header and footer no matter what size any particular page is.  If possible, I would rather not use JavaScript only because I know less about that than HTML/CSS.

I believe I have everything needed on fiddle.  If not, please feel free to let me know.

https://jsfiddle.net/BradAnderson/vcgqrh6y/1/

```
<body>

<header>
     <div id="header"></div>
</header>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>


<p>Click on the element below to open the menu</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" class="opencolor" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</span>



<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>

<script>
imageout=new Image();
imageout.src="Pics/image2.png";
imageover=new Image();
imageover.src="Pics/images2.png";

function image_out(){
document.images['imageout'].src="Pics/image2.png";
}

function image_over(){
document.images['imageout'].src="Pics/images2.png";
}
    </script>

<p>
<h3 class="indent">Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.  </h3> 
<h3 class="indent">Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.  Yadda yadda yadda yadda.</h3></p>  

<footer>
     <div id="footer"></div>
</footer> 

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

hr { background-color: #7093DB; height: 4px; border: 0; }

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #EAEAAE;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2707AB;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #818181;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.opencolor
{
  color:White;
}

p.leftpadding {
    padding-left: 300px;
}

.indent {
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

Comment: a suggestion is to better reorganize your code . CSS / HTML/ JS ... don't scramble everything and make it hard for you and us

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess what I should have done is asked the question when I first noticed the problem instead of trying to pick out what was needed later on.  Live and learn......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve, try to use for `.sidenav` a different `height` and `margin` for example:

```
.sidenav {
height: 80%;
margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #EAEAAE;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 60px;}
```

Comment: That is almost it.  It stops it from going over the footer, but still goes over the header.  Would padding solve the problem?

Comment: Try to increase the size of margin top -> e.g.: margin: 90px 0px 0px 0px;

Comment: Not quite what I wanted overall, but it is a million times better than what I had.  Mucho Gracis!